# How to re-export everything from a star (*) import in a python __init__.py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

When I write a python library, I often end up with something like this:

```
/my_lib
   __init__.py
   module_a.py
   module_b.py
   ...
```

Now lets suppose that `module_a` and `module_b` are very big, and define a lot public and non-public methods. E.g.:

```py
import ...
from ... import ...
... etc

__all__ = [
    "PublicClass",
    "public_fn",
    "PUBLIC_STATIC_VAR",
    "OtherPublicClass",
    ...
]

class _PrivateClass:
    ...
```

I put a lot of effort in curating a well thought out list of symbols to export in `__all__`. Now in my `__init__.py` I would like to do this (which does not work of course):

```py
from my_lib.module_a import * as module_a
from my_lib.module_b import * as module_b
from third_party_lib import * as third_party
from other_lib import OtherA, OtherB

__all__ = [
    *module_a,
    *module_b,
    *third_party,
    "OtherA",
    "OtherB",
]
```

In essence, what I want is that, if someone imports `my_lib`, they can access all public symbols from `module_a`, `module_b` and `third_party` from the same namespace. I.e.:

```py
import my_lib

obj1 = my_lib.pub_fn_from_module_a()
obj2 = my_lib.PubClassFromModuleB()
obj3 = my_lib.CONSTANT_FROM_THIRD_PARTY_LIB
obj4 = my_lib.OtherA()
obj5 = my_lib.OtherB()
```

### Poor solutions:

#### 1. Implicit `__all__`

I know I can do:

```py
from my_lib.module_a import *
from my_lib.module_b import *
from third_party_lib import *
from other_lib import OtherA, OtherB

# __all__ is not defined in __init__.py
```

This will implicitly define `__all__` and achieves the desired behavior, but it is not possible for static code analysis tools to distinguish this from dead code. For example pre-commit hooks or code formatting tools may delete these imports.

#### 2. Re-type everything

I can also do:

```py
from my_lib.module_a import (
    # <type all public symbols from module_a here>
)
from my_lib.module_b import (
    # <type all public symbols from module_b here>
)
from third_party_lib import (
    # <type all public symbols from third_party_lib here>
)
from other_lib import OtherA, OtherB

__all__ = [
    # <copy-paste the body of module_a.__all__ here>
    # <copy-paste the body of module_b.__all__ here>
    # <type all public symbols from third_party_lib here>
    "OtherA",
    "OtherB",
]
```

But now I basically have to retype the name of each symbol in `module_a` three times, once in `module_a.__all__`, once in the import of `__init__.py` and once in the `__all__` definition in `__init__.py`. The same goes for `module_b`, I also need make sure al 3 remain in sync during development.

#### 3. re-use `__all__`

This kind of works, but looks really awkward:

```py
from my_lib.module_a import * as module_a
from my_lib.module_b import * as module_b
from my_lib import module_a, module_b
from third_party_lib import * as third_party
from other_lib import OtherA, OtherB

# only purpose of `_keep` is to fake the usage of a few symbols 
# such that the star imports are not flagged as dead code.
# It does nothing at runtime.
def _keep(x): pass

_keep(random_symbol_from_module_a)
_keep(random_symbol_from_module_b)
_keep(random_symbol_form_third_party)

__all__ = [
    *module_a.__all__,
    *module_b.__all__,
    *third_party_lib.__all__,
    "OtherA",
    "OtherB",
]
```

The star imports (`from ... import *`) are required because e.g. pycharm or other static code analysis tools can't infer what the `*module_a.__all__` statement does. So without the star imports, static code analysis tools will report missing imports everywhere.

Comment: Why would you like to merge module_a and module_b  functions ? You put some great effort to organise them into 2 carefully built module that I guess have a lot of business sense. I would recommend you to provide this sub-module organisation to users. For example `scikit-learn` does something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by '_I would recommend you to provide this sub-module organisation to users_', can you elaborate on that? To answer your first question: module_a and module_b may form a logical grouping from a development perspective. E.g. module_a handles IO of certain file types, and module_b handles visualization. They don't need each other but it makes sense for an end user to use them together.

Comment: I would recommend to have `__all__ = ['module_a', 'module_b']` so that user access functions with the code `from your_module.module_a import io_handler`

Comment: You're not wrong, and I'm not claiming that  your approach is better or worse than what I'm trying to achieve. But that is not what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: Yep, this is why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer ;). 
The other recommandation that I would have is don't make the code  more ugly for your linter or static analysis. The linter should help you, if it doesn't escape the file or the line.

Answer (score 0):

A good example of your desired code pattern can be found in the `__init__` module of the `asyncio` package of the standard library:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b1f8398d0ffe3c8ba2cca79d0c0f19a6a34e72a/Lib/asyncio/__init__.py

```
from .base_events import *
from .coroutines import *
from .events import *
from .exceptions import *
from .futures import *
from .locks import *
from .protocols import *
from .runners import *
from .queues import *
from .streams import *
from .subprocess import *
from .tasks import *
from .taskgroups import *
from .timeouts import *
from .threads import *
from .transports import *

__all__ = (base_events.__all__ +
           coroutines.__all__ +
           events.__all__ +
           exceptions.__all__ +
           futures.__all__ +
           locks.__all__ +
           protocols.__all__ +
           runners.__all__ +
           queues.__all__ +
           streams.__all__ +
           subprocess.__all__ +
           tasks.__all__ +
           taskgroups.__all__ +
           threads.__all__ +
           timeouts.__all__ +
           transports.__all__)
```

As you can see, it adopts basically the same approach as your solution #3, but instead of unpacking all the `__all__` lists with the `*` operator as you do it uses the `+` operator to join them, and as it turns out most static analyzers are better equipped to statically infer the resulting value of a list joined with the `+` operator, so with this approach the static analyzers would not complain about missing imports everywhere.